# How can I determine a user_id based on an email address in App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, email, user-identification

The newest App Engine SDK (1.2.1) has an API call to compute an ID for a user account based on his email address.  (The ID remains the same even if the user changes his address later.)  See this [question about unique, opaque user IDs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/778965/generating-unique-and-opaque-user-ids-in-google-app-engine) for information.  However, I have a problem with this API call.

`user_id()` works for logged-in users (i.e. from `users.get_current_user)`, but it returns `None` for objects created by the `users.User()` constructor.**  What gives?

For example, using the excellent [App Engine Console](http://con.appspot.com), this code **does not work**.

```
>>> import google.appengine.api.users
>>> me = google.appengine.api.users.get_current_user()
>>> me
users.User(email='jason.h.smith@gmail.com',_user_id='105261964646342707921')
>>> me.user_id()
'105261964646342707921'
>>> somebody = google.appengine.api.users.User('someone@gmail.com')
>>> somebody
users.User(email='someone@gmail.com')
>>>somebody.user_id()
>>> type(somebody.user_id())
<type 'NoneType'>
```

I want a simple way to convert an email address to a user ID.  *How can I coerce this ID from Google ahead of time; or if it's not possible, why not?*

### Edit: Here is the current workaround.

Thanks to Nick Johnson for his answer.  Here is his solution in action:

```
>>> from google.appengine.ext import db
>>> from google.appengine.api import users
>>> class User(db.Model):
...   user = db.UserProperty(required=True)
...
>>> def email_to_userid(address):
...   """Return a stable user_id string based on an email address, or None if
...   the address is not a valid/existing google account."""
...   u = users.User(address)
...   key = User(user=u).put()
...   obj = User.get(key)
...   return obj.user.user_id()
>>> email_to_userid('jason.h.smith@gmail.com')
u'105261964646342707921'
>>> email_to_userid('this@is-an-invalid-email-address')
>>> email_to_userid('this@is-an-invalid-email-address') is None
True
```

Comment: You might want to add the caveat that if there is no Google account for the given email address, no user ID will be returned.

Comment: Shouldn't you delete the entity at the end of the process?

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Maybe it doesn't work with ndb?

Comment: I confirmed that this works with db, but not with ndb.

Comment: It probably doesn't work for `ndb` because the `ndb` object gets cached in memcache, so the object you `.get` doesn't come from the datastore.

Comment: Does anyone here know how to get the user_id with NDB? I've been stuck on this for a while.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The current workaround is to create a User object, store it to the datastore, and fetch it again. If the email corresponds to a valid Google account, the User object in the returned entity will have its user_id field populated.

Comment: Thanks. I am testing this right now and if it works, I'll upvote and accept your answer.

Comment: +1, It works. I will put some example code in the edited question, so hopefully this question can become the canonical answer for how to convert an email address to a user ID.

Comment: Same thing i want to DO For Android. . .  Is Anybudy help me Please. . .  Thanks in Advance. .  .

Comment: Hi Nick, I'm confused, apologies if I'm being dumb.  Are you saying with the above workaround that it provides a way of programmatically testing whether the supplied email address is associated with a valid Gmail account - coz that is my legitimate use case.  However, first of all I can't get it work using Java.  Secondly it seems to contradict this answer, which implies exactly this sort of test is deliberately not supported:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13313877/how-to-validate-a-gmail-address-in-java/13314114#13314114

Comment: okay, got it working now, so I guess it is possible.  thanks!

Comment: Does anyone have a code snippet for doing this in Java?

Answer (score 1):

To make the proposed solution work with NDB, just add use_cache=False, use_memcache=False to the get method. That is:
 `obj = key.get(use_cache=False, use_memcache=False)`
This guarantees getting the entity from the Datastore with the user_id param populated (only if this is a valid Google account).