# How to get Google UserId from active user session in App Maker?

Tags: google-app-maker

Is there a way to get "User Google Id" from the session in App Maker. In the documentation its only mentioned how to retrieve the email of the logged in user `Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()` but no where it says how to get the id. I need this because the user email might sometimes changes. So I need the user id to keep track of users and related permission tasks. Or is there something I'm missing out here in how this should be implemented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A team member has figured it out. This should be done using Apps Script - which works within App Maker environment using server side script.

```
var GoogleUser = (function (){

    /**
     * 
     * @param {string} email
     */
    function getUserObjByEmail(email){

        // Same as using AdminDirectory class.
        var apiUrl = "https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users/"+email+"?fields=id";
        var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
        var header = {"Authorization":"Bearer " + token};
        var options = {
            "method": "GET",
            "headers": header
        };

        var response = JSON.parse(UrlFetchApp.fetch(apiUrl, options));
        return response;
    }


    /**
     * 
     * @param {string} email - User email.
     */
    function getIdByEmail(email){
        return getUserObjByEmail(email)['id'];
    }

    var publicApi = {
        getIdByEmail: getIdByEmail
    };

    return publicApi;
})();
```

Note that using `var apiUrl = "https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users/"+email+"?fields=id";` is not going to be asynchronously called because its already happening in the server.

Answer (score 2):

Yet an easier way to find Google Id simply using [the Directory model](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/models/directory). Although its mentioned in documentation that there is a way to get current signed in user id ( which is Google Id), its not clearly stated how - maybe documentation could be improved here. Another problem is that in many occasions the email of current active user is referred to as the id for example in deprecated method `Session.getActiveUser().getUserLoginId()`. Anyways this is a proper way to get the id.

```
var query = app.models.Directory.newQuery();
query.filters.PrimaryEmail._equals = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
var result = query.run();
var GoogleId = result[0]._key;
```

So with this GoogleId you can safely relate different models with each other and not worry that database integrity might break if an already referenced user email is changed.

Relating the different models could be done simply by creating a model that acts as a wrapper model around the Directory model and storing GoogleId in it. Then linking that model to other models where you want to track user related data because unfortunately we can not directly link The Directory Model to other models.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a dup of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/816372/how-can-i-determine-a-user-id-based-on-an-email-address-in-app-engine)?

I think this will solve your problem, even though it's a bit of a hack.

Comment: Thank you for mentioning the post but its outdated. I have posted the updated solution.